# What does this mean?

Tags: linux, shared-objects

```
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libpng12.so.0.1.2.35 and libpng12.so.0.10.0 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libevent_core-1.4.so.2 and libevent_core-1.4.so.2.1.2 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
```

Does it mean anything wrong?

**UPDATE**

output of `ll /usr/lib/libpng12*`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 351352 12-17 13:22 /usr/lib/libpng12.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 12-17 13:22 /usr/lib/libpng12.so -> libpng12.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 12-17 13:23 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153956 2009-03-25 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 266077 12-17 13:22 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0.1.2.35
```

Comment: Please provide more context for your question.

Comment: Explain where you see that, what you were doing when you see that, and then write a better title.

Answer (score 2):

I think that means you have two symlinks pointing to the same library but their version numbers appear differently. Try running...

```
ls -alh /usr/lib
```

To confirm what I am saying. As far as them being "wrong" I don't know but I would expect some apps to balk when they don't get the version they asked for during linking.

Comment: I've pasted output of `ll /usr/lib/libpng12*` above.